# How to pause Iron Router template rendering until all data is available?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Current common Iron Router pattern is to display a loading template while waiting for data to be available. But I would prefer simply to wait on the previous rendered template/data context until data is available and then trigger rerendering. Data is quickly available, so that short flicker of loading template is worse than a short delay user will experience after a link click.

Answer (score 1):

Does this pattern work for you?

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'nameOfTemplate',
    data: function() { return CollectionName.find({title: 'nameOfMongoDBQuery'}); }, 
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('nameOfSubscription'); } // waits until resources arrive before rendering page
});
```

Comment: No, this pattern still displays the default loading template while waiting for the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify an explicit `action` function like so:

```
action: function() {
    if (this.ready()) {
        this.render();
    }    
}
```

This will just not render anything until the data is around.